# Multiple models in one form

Tags: python, django, forms, model

I want to use two models in one form. Models have many to many relation, what would be the nicest solution for that? I tried formset, but I saw only one model's fields, not both.

My model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=400)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class EventTime(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    event = models.ManyToManyField(Event)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a model form for each form.

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('title', 'description', 'location')

class EventTimeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('start_time',)
```

Note that the `event` field has been left out, because we want to link the event time object to the new event we are creating.

In your view, you need to pass both forms to the template context. Using prefix is a good idea when using multiple forms, it prevents field names from clashing in `request.POST`

```
event_form = EventForm(prefix="event")
event_time_form = EventTimeForm(prefix="eventtime")
```

In the template, you can include multiple forms in the same form tag.

```
<form method="post">
    {{ event_form }}
    {{ event_time_form }}
</form>
```

When processing the POST request, check that both forms are valid. After saving both forms, you can link the event and event time together.

```
event_form = EventForm(request.POST, prefix="event")
event_time_form = EventTimeForm(request.POST, prefix="eventtime")

if event_form.is_valid() and event_time_form.is_valid():
    event = event_form.save()
    event_time = event_time_form.save()
    event_time.event.add(event)
```

Comment: The prefix is very nice, but there is a trap : if you want to access to the field values when the form is valid, remove the prefix from the name field ; for instance, `if event_form.is_valid(): thetitle = event_form.cleaned_data['title']`